# Getting Records Based on Count of Associated Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use a where statement like the following:

```
BaseProduct.where(BaseProduct.products.count => 1)
```

This doesn't work.I get undefined method 'products' for class xyz.

In rails console though, I can do

```
BaseProduct.first.products
```

and get good output.

How do I get the records where the associated model count is 1?

Associations:

```
class BaseProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :base_product
end
```

Comment: you get error because in BaseProduct.products.count BaseProduct is class not object of BaseProduct

Comment: you want all the BaseProduct have its related products.count > 1 ?

Comment: yeah How do I get the records where the associated model count is > 1?

Comment: Try: `BaseProduct.select("base_products.*, COUNT(products.id) AS count_products_id").includes(:products).group("products.base_product_id").where('count_products_id > ?', 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this:

```
BaseProduct.select("base_products.*, COUNT(products.id) AS cp")
    .joins("INNER join products ON products .base_product_id= products.id")
    .group("products.base_product_id")
    .having("cp > 1")
```

Comment: <ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "cp" does not exist
LINE 1: ... products.id GROUP BY products.base_product_id HAVING cp > 1

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
Product.select('base_product_id, count(base_product_id) as c').includes('base_product').group('products.base_product_id').having('c > 1')
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error 'undefined column c', just like the other answer I got undefined column 'cp' -- I'm guessing it's probably something I'm doing now.

Comment: 'c' is alias column name and it works in group by, order by and having clause. It will not work in where clause. I could run above query in my rails console successfully. Which rails version are you using?

Comment: Rails 4.1... Ruby 2.1.2